# Can my weed wacker designed for .065" (1.651 mm) trimmer line handle .08" (2 mm) one?

Tags: tools, string-trimmer

I have a Ryobi P2200 hybrid weed whacker. It takes .065" (1.651 mm) trimmer line. I have found better deals and much better shaped line. I have found a piece of (plastic) wire that was exactly .08" (2 mm) and fed it through the hole and it fits with some room left over (did not run with wire in, very dangerous!).

I would naturally think there is a great possibility that it would work. But would there be a reason why it does not say in the manual it can handle .08" (2 mm)? Will it mess with how it auto feeds, how it performs etc. Would it be worth trying? Not that I go spend $8 at a local store and it does not work.

[image]

Comment: I think this gardening question is a proper one. Could you take a photo of your string trimmer (especially its underpart) and the wire you’re considering? That would undoubtedly be helpful for future readers with similar aims.

Comment: "found a piece of wire that was exactly .08": is this actually (metal) wire, or is it .08 plastic string designed for use in other models of trimmers? Wire may be more durable but is much less safe than using plastic string that is designed for use in trimmers.

Comment: I will be uploading a photo later as requested. The wire is indeed metal since I have no .08" line. I do not use the wire for my string trimmer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it could fit (in a pinch). I have successfully used different guages of line on other weedeaters (although I have never used this particular weed eater). So I'm just going to list some of the possible pros and cons.

Pros

1. 0.08" is commonly available, and might be cheaper (by the foot) in some areas.
2. Thicker line should be more durable; so if it's about the same price, but it lasts longer, it would be generally more economical.
3. Trying will not cause the weedeater to explode.
4. knowing whether or not it can use a different string will be handy
   for future reference (it's better to test it at your convenience
   than when your options are limited).

Cons

1. Thicker line might require more power to move/cut through weeds.
2. Thicker line will be shorter on the spool (in other words, you might
   get 6 ft of 0.065" line on the spool vs. 4 ft of 0.08".
3. Feeding thicker line though the hole (especially during operation)
   might be a problem, causing snarls.
4. Heavier line might cause vibrations (which can lead to a bent rod).

Comment: this is a great answer.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you for the great answer. And get this, when you mention how .08" may be cheaper than .065". True, that being on of the biggest reasons I ask. In bulk comparison, I could get 3 pounds of .065" trimmer line for $45 or so. .08" trimmer line on the other hand would cost me $32 and I would get 5 pounds!

Comment: I have tried .08 trimmer line (twisted square) and it is working great. It has taken down some weed that the .065 just wasn't handling. The vibrations are almost no worse than the .065, so I do not see it coming into affect on the rod. And as you have said with 1 and 2 they hold true. 1) yes, but there is still a huge different in performance, the only time when it becomes a bug is when the battery starts to die, and since its lithium it is only with the last few minutes. Unless I have it on the cord. 2) VERY true, I could get 20 feet of .065 line on the spool...

Comment: ... but since this is a little bigger I could (and I measured for both) only get 10-11 feet. With one exeption, I have found this line to last much longer(as you have said) so I think it was well worth the difference. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Ljk2000 Thanks for updating us with your findings. It's good info to know.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that bump and go trimmer head!  What headaches!  Take it in and get a 'fixed head' for that trimmer.  Get rid of the shield.  The shield is supposed to be for safety but it is hard to see exactly what you are doing and I think that is far more important and safer to see what you are trimming.  I did this for a living and almost! went into competition with my little weed wacker!  All my trimmers were fitted with fixed heads and shields removed.  One has to be very vigilant the direction they chose and to make sure no kids, no pets, no windows are in that path and continually check.  Shields just make for a false sense of security.

ALWAYS WERE SAFETY GLASSES.  ALWAYS.

For fixed heads one needs to cut lengths of line, fit them through the holes that are made to hold onto that line, then cut as close as you can to equal lengths. Pull them together above the head (where the bump and go used to be) as centered as possible and cut to 4 or 5". The equal lengths or weights the trimmer has to spin is so important for the life of the motor and the precision of cutting that I also take that trimmer, turn it upside down, turn it on.  Then on concrete or a big boulder (making sure where the lines are throwing) touch the lines lightly on the surface.  You'll hear the change in RPM go up as the two lines become perfectly equal.  The length of those lines are usually no more than 4" each.  Any longer and your trimming will be out of control.  Again, look where the line is tossing!!

DO NOT USE WIRE...you need to use the plastic!!  Get the star cross section. It is imperative that you use the plastic, there is no way to get the lines equal and when pieces of wire go flying, very dangerous.  I've never used wire.

And wear safety glasses!!  Watch for kids, people, pets and windows.  Those tiny little rocks become gnarly rockets.  Get used to trimming (edges of lawns) on both sides to be able to change your direction.  Mow your lawn first, then trim edges making sure the height of grass is the height you've mowed the rest of the lawn.  No shorter than 3"!!!  Do the trimming next to concrete last as that melts your lines and make for more change outs.  Find the perfect length of line and cut 3 or 4 lines to loop in your belt loop and take with you.  Also take a small pair of cutters.  Be precise with your gas and oil mixture!  Do not guess.  And never use gasoline with ethanol!!!

And wear safety glasses!!  Grins, sorry, but I had two of my guys, each took his glasses off when he went around the corner and each poked an eye out.  Kids...sometimes the more 'parent' one is the more childish they become.

Comment: I can ensure you I do wear both safety glasses and hearing protection :). This is some good advice and thank you much for it. But my trimmer is not as you may think it is. It runs off either a cord or battery, and the head is auto feed, meaning every time I want more line I just need to 'stop' and let the thing slow down then right back on and boom I have more. I was tempted to remove the shield, but it cuts the line to perfect length so I am going to leave it. I will be keeping this info in mind, for one day I might get a gas trimmer. Thank you very much good person.

Comment: And also I never used wire, I was implying that I measured the wire to be the same size as .08" trimmer line. And I did insert it from the outside to get a feel for how much room there would be. But my neighbor used to use it... until it landed in his leg!

Comment: On his leg?  Ouch!  I am glad you are so smart Ljk...I will stop whenever I see these maintenance crews or homeowners trimming without glasses and read them the 'riot act'!  I will only use gas powered trimmers, blowers and mowers!  Check out Stihl, I am not sure of any other brands that are new or better these days.  You will LOVE gas powered!  Since you have an electric or underpowered trimmer, don't go with the heavier line.  Worth the money to get the .065, comes on even bigger spools for even less per foot.  Get a fixed head and remove the shield.  Smaller dia. line gives better accuracy.

Comment: This is a good post, but doesn't address the question.

Comment: sure, it may not address the question but it was still good information for me.  I did learn a good few things from this fine person.

Comment: Thanks, Ljk.  I think I did answer the question and it was a big no.  Wrong size, wrong head, major headaches.  Whatever, I do know what everyone using a line trimmer should know without having to learn the hard way.  I smile with your adjectives of moi.  Thank you big sweetie. I hope I helped a bit...

Answer (score 0):

My dearly departed Dad left us a spool of .080 the size of a battleship gun round, so this should last us our lifetimes! LOL. Our pootie little Ryobi 18V weed-eater bit the dust, so we got a 2nd hand 40V Black & Decker that cautioned "only use .065 line".

Well, our donor also gave us pre-wound spools of that size, but I could not rewind the empty ones with the thicker plastic line, so I awl-ed out the keeper hole and slot to accept it. Tried it and it works absolutely fine! I did Dremel sharpen the cutter blade on the housing after a nice scraper cleaning.

BTW & fyi, those pre-wound spools are kept in place with reinforced packing tape, so it takes longer to remove that mess than to simply wind your own, like I did from dear ol' Dad's "barrel-O-trimmerline"! Hope that helps Y'all.

The reason we all need a clean and sharp cutoff blade on the housing is because otherwise it will "gum" the line, and sling out more of it until inertial forces pull wasteful amount of material out of your magazine. Sorta like eating corn on the cob with no teeth. Apologies in advance for being a nerd & an engineer.